# Should I use a ContextMenu to show a couple of buttons?

Tags: wpf, button, contextmenu

I am developing a WPF application and I want the following functionality: If a user right clicks on a progress bar a small context menu should popup at the clicked position. This menu should just contain a couple of buttons which are lined up horizontally. Should I use the ContextMenu for this or are there better suitable WPF elements?
I tried a ContextMenu and this is how it looks like:

[image]

This is the XAML:

```
        <ProgressBar x:Name="PgF" Height="10" Value="{Binding Path=FileCurrentMs}" Maximum="{Binding Path=FileLengthMs}">
            <ProgressBar.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="A"/>
                        <Button Content="B"/>
                        <Button Content="C"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ProgressBar.ContextMenu>
        </ProgressBar>
```

In the ContextMenu I have the space to the left and to the right which I don’t want and I read in other posts that it is not simple just to remove this space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="PgF" Height="10" Value="{Binding Path=FileCurrentMs}" Maximum="{Binding Path=FileLengthMs}">
    <ProgressBar.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="A" Margin="2"/>
                            <Button Content="B" Margin="2"/>
                            <Button Content="C" Margin="2"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuItem.Template>
            </MenuItem>

        </ContextMenu>          
    </ProgressBar.ContextMenu>
</ProgressBar>
```

You need to put all buttons in a single menu item :) good luck